# Creating custom rollups with SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am currently working on a requirement as follows and would appreciate some help in figuring out a way to configure the aggregation of my measure:

I have a fact table that contains the following Item ID, DateID,StoreID, ReceivedComments. The way received comments work is that on a daily basis a new record is created that adds to the value of received comments (for example if Item 5 in Store 5 on 1 Jan had 23 Received Comments and it received 5 comments the following day, the row for Jan 2 would be Item 5, Store 5, Jan 2, 28)

We created a measure using MAX and it works fine whenever Item ID is used in the query. When we start moving to a higher level the max produces wrong results. Our requirement is to setup the measure to be as follows:

If the member selected is on the Item Level then MAX, if it's on any other level (Date or Store) then the measure should aggregate the Max of all Items under this date or store.

Due to the business rules and structure of the database Store and Item are different dimensions so I can not include them in 1 Hierarchy.

We have been playing around with Custom RollUps but so far haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested using ISLEAF to determine the level, Instead of using ISLeaf i went with  AS CASE WHEN [Item].[ItemID].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL IS [Item].[ItemID].[(All)] so I don't have to account for other dimensions such as Date, Store, etc as I have several other dimensions that all behave the same way.

And then I went with this formula to determine the Sum of the Max of the items in a particular store like this:

SUM({[Item].[Item ID].children},[Measures].[ReceivedComments]), Now I expect some performance issues with this measure but we are currently running some tests to see if it's gonna be reliable to work with it on actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by using a more traditional approach to your fact table.  Instead of keeping a cumulative count in the ReceivedComments column, I would keep only the number of comments received THAT DAY.

That way, instead of using MAX, you can create your measure using SUM, and it will automatically rollup when you go to higher levels.

The only disadvantage I can see to this approach is that you will need to use a range of dates, instead of only the most recent date, to get a full total of all the comments for a given item/store/date.   But that's a very small change to your MDX.

Comment: Unfortunately the data coming makes it very hard and unreliable to implement this approach.